# Could not build wheels for oracledb, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, python-oracledb

I was trying to install a specific of oracledb==1.0.3 via Anaconda Prompt by running the following script

pip install oracledb==1.0.3

I have created a virtual environment where I was trying to install that specific package.

```
Note: I could install oracledb which is 1.3.2
```

I am getting the following error;

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for oracledb
Failed to build oracledb
ERROR: Could not build wheels for oracledb, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've referred similar posts, tried all possible ways to fix this error. I need to install this package to avoid error while trying to read data from a oracle database via jupyter

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're trying to install 1.0.3? Why do that if 1.3.2 is working for you?

Comment: You can always download the specific version manually. It would help if you were clear on what Python version and platform you are using, too!

Comment: with the latest version i am getting this error "time zones are not supported in thin mode". Therefore, need to install 1.0.3

Comment: Unsure how to install it manually

Comment: 1.0.3 doesn't support named time zones either! It simply returned incorrect data. As for installing manually, you can use pip and install the local file name as the installation source.